# Django-Viewflow, customize archive view

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

I am trying to customize the default `/workflow/archive/` view from Viewflow.
(as in http://demo.viewflow.io/workflow/archive/)

I need to remove some of the columns and add some additional ones specific to my task.

I can't seem to find an easy way. I have been digging and have found that I can try to override the class `viewflow.frontend.views.AllArchiveListView` and adding the mapping

```
url('^test/', AllArchiveListView.as_view())
```

but I get no data when doing that (seems like the `flow_classes` internal parameter is empty when it gets called like that)

I have also tried to create the viewflow/site_archive.html template but seems overkill.

Any ideas that may point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To customize a common frontend list view, you need to replace `viewflow.frontend` with you own frontend application. To simplify development, you can inherit from viewflow frontend base classes

```
# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from viewflow.frontend.apps import ViewflowFrontendConfig

class FrontendConfig(ViewflowFrontendConfig):
    viewset = 'frontend.viewset.FrontendViewSet'

    def register(self, flow_class, viewset_class=None):
        super().register(flow_class, viewset_class=viewset_class)

# views.py
from viewflow.frontend.views import AllTaskListView as BaseAllTaskListView

class AllTaskListView(BaseAllTaskListView):
    list_display = [
        'task_hash', 'description'
    ]

# viewset.py
from viewflow.frontend.viewset import FrontendViewSet as BaseFrontendViewSet
class FrontendViewSet(BaseFrontendViewSet):
    inbox_view_class = views.AllTaskListView
```

Comment: I tried the approach you suggest here. However it is not clear how to make my app use FrontEndConfig. It was still resorting to the one from ViewFlow.

Comment: Just adding in here additional info I needed to get this up and running. First, this example assumes the app name "frontend". Additionally, I needed to add "default_app_config = 'frontend.apps.FrontendConfig'" to __init__.py. Finally, make sure to comment out "viewflow.frontend" from the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.